Add a flag based on another dataset
Suppose I have a dataset "DB1" with x columns (variables). You have a variable named "my_identifiers". Then you have another dataset "DB2" with one variable named "my_identifiers_subset". Then if the values of "my_identifiers_subset" from DB2 are in "my_identifiers" from DB1 you add a column flag in DB1 containing 1 otherwise 0.
I know how to deal with this when the comparison involves the same dataset but I don't know how to deal with this, when comparing with an external dataset.
          data DB1;
          input ID$ my_identifiers$;
          cards;
          1 345 
          1 45 
          2 678
          3 432
          3 432
          4 7
          ..........
          ;


          data DB2;
          input my_identifiers_subset$;
          cards;
          345  
          432
          44
          ..........
          ;

Desired output:
          data DB3;
          input ID$ my_identifiers$ Index$;
          cards;
          1 345 1
          1 45  0
          2 678 0
          3 432 1
          3 432 1
          4 7   0
          ..........
          ;


You could do a proc sql and join the 2 datasets together. I can see if I can write out an answer when I'm in front of a computer.

So using a proc sql and joining the 2 datasets might be the easiest solution. You have a couple of different options.
First, you could use an EXISTS with a sub-query to determine whether DB1.my_identifiers is in db2.my_identifiers_subset. Or you could do a LEFT JOIN to achieve the same affect. The only caveat with the 2nd solution is is db2 might have multiple instances of the same my_identifiers_subset, in which case you'd get extra rows.
PROC SQL;

    CREATE TABLE DB3_EXISTS AS
    SELECT *, 
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DB2 WHERE DB2.my_identifiers_subset = DB1.my_identifiers) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END AS INDEX
    FROM DB1
    ;

    CREATE TABLE DB3_LEFT_JOIN AS
    SELECT DB1.*,
        CASE 
            WHEN DB2.my_identifiers_subset IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS INDEX
    FROM DB1
        LEFT JOIN DB2 ON DB2.my_identifiers_subset = DB1.my_identifiers
    ORDER BY DB1.ID
    ;

QUIT;


Some other SQL queries that do the same.  SAS logical evaluations can be assigned and have value 1 for true and 0 for false.
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select DB1.*, DB1.item_id in (select item_id from DB2) as flag
  from DB1
  ;

  create table want as 
  select DB1.*, DB2.item_id is not null
  from DB1 left join DB2 on DB1.item_id = DB2.item_id
  ;


The straight forward method is to MERGE the two datasets.  Make sure the "subset" has unique observations.  Also the variable names must match, but you can use the RENAME= dataset option to fix that.
proc sort data=db1;
  by my_identifiers;
run;
proc sort data=db2(rename=(my_identifiers_subset=my_identifiers))
   nodupkey out=unique_db2;
  by my_identifiers;
run;
data want;
  merge db1(in=in1) unique_db2(in=in2);
  by my_identifiers;
  if in1;
  flag = in2;
run;

If you need the result ordered by ID then add another PROC SORT step.
If the subset is small enough to put into a hash object then you can use that so that you do not have to sort either dataset (the hash object will effectively sort the subset).  You can again use the RENAME= dataset option to make the variable names match.
data want;
 set db1;
 if _n_=1 then do;
   declare hash h(dataset:'db2(rename=(my_identifiers_subset=my_identifiers))');
   h.definekey('my_identifiers');
   h.definedone();
 end;
 flag = 0=h.find();
run;

